# How to show that $\Gamma\vdash (\varphi\to\neg\varphi)\to\varphi$?

Tags: propositional-calculus

> **Problem.**
>
> Let $(\mathscr{L},\vdash)$ be a logic and $\Gamma\subseteq\mathscr{L}$ be a set of formulas such that for some $\varphi\in\mathscr{L}$ we have $$\Gamma\vdash\varphi\to\neg\varphi$$ $$\Gamma\vdash\neg\varphi\to\varphi$$Then show that, $$\Gamma\vdash(\varphi\to\neg\varphi)\to\varphi$$using only the following,
>
> $\color{crimson}{\text{Axiom 1.}}\  P\to (Q\to P)$
>
> $\color{crimson}{\text{Axiom 2.}}\  (S\to (P\to Q))\to((S\to P)\to (S\to Q))$
>
> $\color{crimson}{\text{Axiom 3.}}\  (\neg Q\to\neg P)\to(P\to Q)$
>
> $\color{crimson}{\text{Rule of Inference.}}$ [Modus Ponens](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj8i9j2vZHPAhVLn5QKHVpiC0YQFggmMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FModus_ponens&usg=AFQjCNGjiX3Tbw5h49jNotuefUM9xvBIDw).
>
> $\color{crimson}{\text{Theorem.}}$ [Deduction Theorem](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj8i9j2vZHPAhVLn5QKHVpiC0YQFggmMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FModus_ponens&usg=AFQjCNGjiX3Tbw5h49jNotuefUM9xvBIDw).

I have tried for some hours to find a proof of the claim but couldn't succeed. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the fastest way, but it works:

First prove Hypothetical Syllogism ($\{A \rightarrow B, B \rightarrow C \} \vDash A \rightarrow C$) as a derived inference principle:

1. $A \rightarrow B$ Premise
2. $B \rightarrow C$ Premise
3. $(B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow  (A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C))$ Axiom 1
4. $A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)$ MP 2,3
5. $(A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)) \rightarrow ((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C))$  Axiom 2
6. $(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C)$ MP 4,5
7. $A \rightarrow C$ MP 1,6

And now:

1. $\neg \varphi \rightarrow (\neg \neg (\varphi \rightarrow \neg \varphi) \rightarrow \neg \varphi)$ Axiom 1
2. $(\neg \neg (\varphi \rightarrow \neg \varphi) \rightarrow \neg \varphi) \rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow \neg (\varphi \rightarrow \neg \varphi))$ Axiom 3
3. $\neg \varphi \rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow \neg (\varphi \rightarrow \neg \varphi))$ Hypothetical Syllogism 1,2
4. $(\neg \varphi \rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow \neg (\varphi \rightarrow \neg \varphi))) \rightarrow ((\neg \varphi \rightarrow \varphi) \rightarrow (\neg \varphi \rightarrow \neg (\varphi \rightarrow \neg \varphi)))$ Axiom 2
5. $(\neg \varphi \rightarrow \varphi) \rightarrow (\neg \varphi \rightarrow \neg (\varphi \rightarrow \neg \varphi))$ MP 3,4
6. $\neg \varphi \rightarrow \varphi$ Premise
7. $\neg \varphi \rightarrow \neg (\varphi \rightarrow \neg \varphi)$ MP 5,6
8. $(\neg \varphi \rightarrow \neg (\varphi \rightarrow \neg \varphi)) \rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow \neg \varphi) \rightarrow \varphi)$ Axiom 3
9. $(\varphi \rightarrow \neg \varphi) \rightarrow \varphi$ MP 7,8

Comment: "This may not be the fastest way."

Basically, it's possible to give Prover9 something like the axioms and the assumptions (just treat the letter $\phi$ like some constant like 'a') with no help whatsoever and there's something like a solution produced/hinted at in less than 2 one-hundreths of a second.  No doubt, it took you orders of seconds longer... :)

Comment: @DougSpoonwood  Yeah, just a *little* longer :)